# Updating multiple rows using pyodbc and ping status

Tags: python, operating-system, pyodbc

I am looking to update multiple rows in a single column using os and pyodbc. my code is as follows:

```
def poll():
for x in device_query():
    command = os.system('ping -n 1 %s' % x[4])
    if command == 0 and x[8] == '':
        cursor.execute('insert into CamTable (UnitStatus)', 'online')
        cnxn.commit()
    elif command == 0 and x[8] == 'offline':
        cursor.execute("update CamTable set UnitStatus=? where UnitStaus='offline'", 'online')
        cnxn.commit()
    elif command != 0 and x[8] == '':
        cursor.execute('insert into CamTable (UnitStatus)', 'offline')
        cnxn.commit()
    elif command != 0 and x[8] == 'online':
        cursor.execute('update CamTable set UnitStatus=?', 'offline')
        cnxn.commit()
    else:
        pass
```

However, every row in x[8] updates with the same value. How do I update the specific status of each row?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a WHERE clause or it will update all rows in the table:

```
cursor.execute('update CamTable set UnitStatus=?', 'offline')
```

Please read the documentation here on UPDATE queries and INSERT queries, you seem to have the syntax wrong:

https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/GettingStarted

As another example of incorrect syntax, this:

```
cursor.execute('insert into CamTable (UnitStatus)', 'online')
```

Should be this:

```
cursor.execute('insert into CamTable (UnitStatus) VALUES (?)', 'online')
```

More context would be helpful as well, after you fix syntax, so we can determine where in the if clause you are actually executing. Where are you getting device_query() from?

Answer (score 0):

Updated code is as follows:

```
def poll():
    for x in device_query():
        command = os.system('ping -n 1 %s' % x[4])
        if command == 0 and x[8] == '':
            cursor.execute('insert into CamTable (UnitStatus) VALUES (?)', 'online')
            cnxn.commit()
        elif command == 0 and x[8] == 'offline':
            print 'update'
            cursor.execute("update CamTable set UnitStatus=? where ip=?", 'online', str(x[4]))
            cnxn.commit()
        elif command != 0 and x[8] == '':
            cursor.execute('insert into CamTable (UnitStatus) VALUES (?)', 'offline')
            cnxn.commit()
        elif command != 0 and x[8] == 'online':
            print 'update'
            cursor.execute("update CamTable set UnitStatus=? where ip=?", 'offline', str(x[4]))
            cnxn.commit()
        else:
            pass
```

x[4] will poll the ip address of the device in my database and update accordingly.